# Access object inside of a companion object in scala

Tags: scala, companion-object

I have the following:

```
case class Location(name: String, level: Location.Level)

object Location {
  trait Level
  case object City extends Level
  case object State extends Level
}
```

If I try and access `City` (from another source file), I get an error saying something like

```
found   : model.Location.City.type
required: model.Level
```

I can think of some work-arounds, but I'm wondering if there's a way to keep my names the same i.e. I'd like to access `City` by typing `Location.City`.

EDIT:

I'm accessing it like this:

```
import the.package.name._
Location.City
```

Comment: How and where are you accessing it?

Comment: @LimbSoup, I updated my question. I'm accessing it by wildcard-importing the package and then typing `Location.City`

Comment: Your error message says it all: you are not asking for a `Location.Level` but `model.Level`, where `model` must be either one of your packages or a value and you have a path-dependent type there. So you must have another type `Level` in your code.

Comment: After your edit it's still not clear, that error is a type mismatch, where this type mismatch happens? I can compile your code and create a `Location` quite easily, your edit doesn't make sense because you can't have top level declaration which is not inside some sort of class.

Comment: @0__, you're right. I do have another type `Level`. It was as simple as that. Thanks! Put that in as an answer and I can mark it as correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your error message says it all: you are not asking for a `Location.Level` but `model.Level`, where `model` must be either one of your packages or a value and you have a path-dependent type there. So you must have *another type `Level`* in your code.